# Regex to find commas within quoted elems of csv

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replaces commas with placeholder text within double-quoted elements of a CSV.

For instance, given this line in a CSV: 
     `1,2,"three,four,five",6,7,8,"nine,ten",11,12`

Using this regex (quotes escaped for Java):
     `(?<=\")([^"]+?),([^"]+?)(?=\")`

I replace the first match with:

```
$1<COMMA>$2
```

Which gives me this result string:

```
1,2,"three<COMMA> four, five",6,7,8,"nine,ten",11,12
```

I repeat these steps against the resultString until there are no more matches. Here are the progressive result strings:

```
1,2,"three<COMMA> four, five",6,7,8,"nine,ten",11,12
1,2,"three<COMMA> four<COMMA> five",6,7,8,"nine,ten",11,12
1,2,"three<COMMA> four<COMMA> five",6<COMMA>7,8,"nine,ten",11,12
1,2,"three<COMMA> four<COMMA> five",6<COMMA>7<COMMA>8,"nine,ten",11,12
1,2,"three<COMMA> four<COMMA> five",6<COMMA>7<COMMA>8,"nine<COMMA>ten",11,12
1,2,"three<COMMA> four<COMMA> five",6<COMMA>7<COMMA>8,"nine<COMMA>ten",11,12
```

How can I tweak my regex so it only replaces the "," within the list items and not the delimiters themselves? In the 3rd iteration, I'm getting a match on: ",6,7,8,"

I tried to prevent this by having my lookbehind match only against one dbl quote with no dble quotes around it, or groups of three dbl quotes, but ran into "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" error,

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a csv parser to parse, modify and recreate the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it so that the first matched character inside quotation marks can't be a comma: `(?<=\")([^",][^"]*?),([^"]+?)(?=\")`.

Having said that, I don't think iterating it until it stops iterating like this is a very nice way of doing it. Personally I'd probably split the line into an array of strings using the unescaped columns, then iterate through the array and do a search-and-replace on each `"`-delimited string in the array with the /g modifier. But it's personal choice I suppose.

Comment: That did the trick. I agree with you, now that I've sufficiently banged my head against the wall, that this probably isn't the best approach, but it became an itch I needed to scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google:

```
^(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)$
```

This matches single elements in line of the csv file.

http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2008/10/14/regex-pattern-for-parsing-csv-files-with-embedded-commas-dou.html

Comment: This regex assumes that the `"` character is escaped in CSV as `""`. But CSV isn't very well standardised, and if you're going to give an answer that goes into that level of detail then you should first check how characters are escaped. But with a bit of luck it will turn out that in jbd's case there are no quotation marks that need to be escaped anyway.

Comment: Incidentally, what language are you using?

Comment: I tried this in regexr.com but it matches all the lines.